# Is there a bug in the .NET TimeSpan Class When Calculating TotalMilliseconds?

Tags: .net, epoch, timespan, datetimeoffset

If I execute the following PowerShell script:

```
$> ([DateTime]"2023-10-16T16:56:14.052Z" - [DateTime]"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").TotalMilliseconds
```

It gives the result (based on the TimeSpan object):

```
1697478974052
```

However, if use the DateTimeOffset object instead:

```
$> ([DateTimeOffset]"2023-10-16T16:56:14.052Z").ToUnixTimeMilliseconds
```

I get a different result which appears to be exactly 3600000 milliseconds off (exactly 1 hour). However, this appears to be the correct number of milliseconds since epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

```
1697475374052
```

I had expected both commands to yield the same number of milliseconds. It makes it appear that TimeSpan is incorrectly calculating the number of milliseconds. What am I missing?

Comment: `DateTime` is aware of your current time zone (and therefore DST). If you convert the `DateTime`s to UTC first, the `.TotalMilliseconds` from the `TimeSpan` returns the value you expect.  `(([DateTime]"2023-10-16T16:56:14.052Z").ToUniversalTime() - ([DateTime]"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z").ToUniversalTime()).TotalMilliseconds`

Comment: @Cory, @TP95: What's the point to initializing a `DateTime` object with any specified value? Is not that value representing a specific moment in time regardless of timezone offset? And if you have two `DateTime` objects that each represent their respective moments in time, should not a `TimeSpan` object be able to calculate purely the "span of time" between those moments? This still presents as a bug to me.

Comment: @jad45 refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-8.0#datetime-operations). Conversion operations between time zones (such as between UTC and local time, or between one time zone and another) take daylight saving time into account, but arithmetic and comparison operations do not.

Comment: Type ([DateTime]"2023-10-16T16:56:14.052Z").Kind to see the problem.  You also get local time for the 1970-01-01 literal so technically local time should not be a problem.  Except that in your timezone, Oct 16 was in daylight savings time and Jan 1 wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the time is exactly one hour off, it screams day light savings to me. In the first command with `[DateTime]` its probably taking in your local machine's timezone's daylight saving configuration (1 hour ahead).

The second command is taking the time in UTC as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=net-8.0). UTC has no daylight savings because it serves as a constant frame of reference in which other time zones are relative.